# How to select a good quality frame?

Tags: parts

I have asked a lot of questions here, and most of times, the answers that I get is related with having a good quality frame. But, in my nation, store owner (or mechanics) hardly give any detail regarding any frame, they just see the price and judge a frame as good or not so good.

How exactly to select a good quality frame?

I ride a typical MTB, for commuting, offroad riding, road or touring as well.

I am expecting in terms of material, weight, welds and other relevant areas (which is obviously dont know of).

Comment: "I ride a typical MTB, for commuting, offroad riding, road or touring as well." How much offroad riding do you do? MTBs are generally a poor choice for three out of your four cycling types.

Comment: @Stephen [Here](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4062/do-mudguards-help-if-so-what-are-the-best-for-a-fixie-commuter/4071#4071) are hints about Starx's riding.

Comment: @ChrisW, I suddenly feel like part of this family. :D

Comment: @Stephen Touset, you must be mentioning, commuting, road, and touring but I got only one bike. (Actually two, but both MTBs so one), However, on this question http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2285/is-there-a-all-in-one-bike-that-i-can-use-for-several-types-of-riding, I wanted to know about all in one type of bike, that can do all, but @Gary.Ray, suggested some pretty nice point, and I am sticking to it as well.

Comment: @ChrisW, How did you place the link at `here`?

Comment: `[Markdown help](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/editing-help)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think most any frame is going to suit you just fine -- consider size, riding position, cost, and weight. Outside of that, one generally doesn't have to worry about frame failures or anything of that sort, with the exception of crazy carbon racing frames.

I think this is the point where you go to a local bike shop and try a few of them out -- look at what's available, and choose one you like (that is, that you feel comfortable riding with).

As far as things like welds, you really don't have to worry about the frame failing on you. Better welds are lighter, but that's really the extent of it.

Comment: Would you like suggest any brand in particular? Just your preferences...

Comment: @Starx: I don't have much of a preference. My current bike is a Trek 1000, but that's mainly because that's the main road bike brand sold at my local shop. (They have Specialized and Giant too but those have a slightly more "relaxed"/"touring" riding position) Different brands have slightly different geometries, and one really needs to try a few before one finds one that's comfortable. (My previous bike was a Schwinn and it was awesome too)

Answer (score -1):

*Let's narrow this down a bit...*

A typical MTB for general purpose use: that means aluminium, rather than carbon fibre or beautiful chro-mo steel.

Now let's see who actually makes their own bikes. Trek? They ask some people in Taiwan to give them a quote for their specifications and they then outsource the job to a.n.other factory. That is pretty much the same story with all of the leading 'brands' - they badge engineer, outsource and do anything but make their own stuff.

Meanwhile, in the Taiwanese corner you have Giant. They make the stuff for the other people and make a fair few bikes of their own. They are the ones that have invested in how to hydroform aluminium into beautiful shapes so as to get maximum strength for given quantity of materials. Do you really think they save their better stuff for other people, e.g. the 'Treks and Colnagos' of this world?

If a Giant suits you then get one. And no I do not work for them.

Comment: Why exactly does it matter who manufacturers the frame so long as it's within spec?

Comment: True but price is part of the equation. The better brands make their own stuff rather than by someone else's stuff and slap their logo on it. The situation is different to -say- own brand breakfast cereals vs. the proper brands, again to spec, again from the same factory. The premium products are the ones from the brands that make their own stuff.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your point. (Particularly given that the "premium" Treks are manufactured in the United States) I don't care who builds the thing, so long as it's designed well.